Is there an R function that minimise a bivariate function f
I need to write a code that using the R function constrOptim, minimise an bivariate function. Please tell me what is wrong in the constrOptim , went i run the code i have this warning message
"invalid token in constrOptim(theta=x0, ...)
Please help me to modify the code.

Please share a minimal reproducible example!
